# How to remove istartsurf from browser

Tags: google-chrome, browser, malware

How to remove istartsurf from chrome?

**Context**: I've installed a bunch of extensions after a day I got "istartsurf" as my main search engine in chrome which sends the search to their server and then redirects the search to google making it seem like you searched on google from the start. It takes a split second then you only see google.com in the address bar.

[image]

I've installed

- chrome extensions: **Requestly**, **Toby for Chrome**
- apps: **Java**, **JDK**, **postgresql**.

Can anyone relate to this? as I want to narrow done the source of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Chrome you need to go to **settings** > **Search engine**

1. For **Search engine used in the address bar** set **Google** (or whatever you want)
2. For **Manage search engines** go through to the lists and **remove** anything suspicious.

Similar should be done for other browsers.

If this goes deeper (registry or something else) please let me know so I can update the answer.